# Match regex multi-line while reading the file line by line

Tags: c++, c++11, parsing

I have a file which I read line by line, and do the parsing with a regex which works fine. What I'm parsing is some functions names and their parameters (that's what I capture). In some files the function parameters are written multi-line, like this:

```
result = f(a, b,
c,
d
);
```

If it was written as `result = f(a, b, c, d);`, my regex works fine. How should I deal with the multi-line?

Comment: Read the whole file into a variable and then run your regex.

Comment: It is not about regular expressio, it is how to read the file actually. It is better if you provide a [mcve]

Comment: The file is big, I don't think it's okay to have the whole file content in memory

Comment: Currently you are reading until `'\n'`. But you have to read until `';'` or `");"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are reading until `'\n'`. But you have to read until `';'`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream file("result = f(a, b,\nc,\nd\n);\nresult = f2(a, b,\nc,\nd\n);");

    std::string function;
    while (std::getline(file, function, ';')) {
        std::cout << "function: " << (function[0] == '\n' ? "" : "\n") << function << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally you can reduce each function to one line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string trim(const std::string& s) {
    std::size_t b(0);
    while (s[b] == '\n') {
        ++b;
    }

    std::size_t e(s.length() - 1);
    while (s[e] == '\n') {
        --e;
    }
    return s.substr(b, e - b + 1);
}

std::string& join(std::string& s) {
    std::size_t pos(s.find('\n'));
    while (pos != s.npos) {
        s.replace(pos, 1, "");
        pos = s.find('\n', pos); // continue looking from current location
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::stringstream file("result = f(a, b,\nc,\nd\n);\nresult = f2(a, b,\nc,\nd\n);");

    std::string function;
    while (std::getline(file, function, ';')) {
        function += ';';
        std::cout << "function: " << trim(join(function)) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`trim` removes linebreak before and after each function. `join` removes each linebreak inside a function.

Input:

```
result = f(a, b,
c,
d
);
result = f2(a, b,
c,
d
);
```

Output:

```
function: result = f(a, b,c,d);
function: result = f2(a, b,c,d);
```

Comment: Thanks. When I have a comment after one-line function, like this: `res1  = f1(29); /* get result */\nres2  = f2(31);   /* use it */`, and do `trim(join(...))`, I get the following lines: `res1  = f1(29);` and `/* get result */res2  = f2(31);`. The comment of previous line is appended at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: @user3132457 1. This was not part of your question. 2. Does it change the result of your parser?

Comment: The regex doesn't match anymore

Comment: @user3132457 Your regex ignores comments at the end but not at the beginning? So adept the regex to ignore comments at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a minimal complete example, you might do the following:

- read a line
- if the line ends with a `;` (or `)` depending on what you want) pass the line to the regular expression directly
- if not continue reading the line and append them together (without newline characters of course) until a `;` or `(` is found;
- pass the string resulting from all the appending to the regular expression